# Adding element to xml node

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I came so far, but how do I add an `XElement` in the third place instead of first place?

I have to add it to 2 big files.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var xml = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath(map1));
    var noprovider = xml.Elements("Component").Where(d => !d.Elements("L").Any());
    var prov in noprovider)
    {
        prov.AddFirst(new XElement("L", ""));
    }
    xml.Save(Server.MapPath(map1));
}
```

The XML

```
<Reservedele>
    <Component>
        <Type>Støvsuger</Type>
        <Art>yiryidryi</Art>
        <Bemærkning> adadgadg</Bemærkning>
        <Varenummer>dfgdfg</Varenummer>
        <OprettetAf>John</OprettetAf>
        <Date>28. januar 2017</Date>
    </Component>
</Reservedele>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure to understand your question. Do you mean something like that?

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace XmlTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var xmlText = @"
<Reservedele>
  <Component>
    <Type>Støvsuger</Type>
    <Art>yiryidryi</Art>
    <Bemærkning> adadgadg</Bemærkning>
    <Varenummer>dfgdfg</Varenummer>
    <OprettetAf>John</OprettetAf>
    <Date>28. januar 2017</Date>
  </Component>
</Reservedele>";

            using (var sr = new StringReader(xmlText))
            {
                var xml = XElement.Load(sr);
                var noprovider = xml.Elements("Component").Where(d => !d.Elements("L").Any());

                noprovider.Elements().ElementAt(1).AddAfterSelf(new XElement("L", ""));
                //noprovider.Elements("Art").First().AddAfterSelf(new XElement("L", ""));

                Console.WriteLine(xml.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key ...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @TheNewone if the answer is correct, please consider marking it as Accepted

Answer (score 0):

Check XmlNode.InsertAfter and XmlNode.InsertBefore methods. Visit https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.insertbefore(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you to use

```
        System.Xml.XmlDocument myDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

        try
        {
            myDoc.Load(XMLFullFileName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Loading failed!", e);
        }
```

Then you can iterate myDoc with all its children and elements and append or insert as you wish. Have a look at [XmlDocument-Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=DE-DE&k=k(System.Xml.XmlDocument);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

Comment: Switching from `XDocument` to `XmlDocument` is unnecessary and doesn't provide any benefits.  Also, you aren't answering the question.